# CSS Sticky attribute is not working

Tags: css, frontend, html

I am using sticky attribute in my following code section but I am unable to get the desired result for which sticky attribute is used:

```
<div style="position: sticky; top: 0;">
    <a href="NewFile.html">TUTORIALS</a>
    <a href="#">REFERENCES</a>
    <a href="#">EXAMPLES</a>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" id="MyFacebook">MY FACEBOOK PAGE</a>
</div>
```

Anybody here can tell why is this happening and why sticky attribute is not working in the code above?

Comment: So you want us to guess a) what is going wrong, and b) what your expected behaviour is, right?

Comment: What are you expecting? I have copied into codepen and it sticks to the top?

Comment: In what browser are you trying? Not all support this.

Comment: I am using Google Chrome @putvande

Comment: In my above code, I want the <div> element to "stick" in place when it approaches the top place of browser window (top: 0) instead of scrolling up along with other content. @connexo

Comment: @James Yes Its working there but not in my browser (Google Chrome Version 65.0.3325.181)